# Items that a Table data cell may contain in HTML

Tags: html, web

Probably quite a basic question but i am revising for an exam and i am going over past papers and i have come across a question which i am not 100% sure about... (the reason im asking here is due to answers are not given out... :|... and also i always get helpful and awesome answers on Stackoverflow :D)

The question is 'Table data cells may contain:'

(a) tables

(b) lists

(c) forms

(d) all of the above

only 1 correct answer btw... so i would say that the answer is 'd' initially, as i understand tables and lists are some of the many things that can be in a data cell but i am unsure if forms can be. I would think they could be in a table data cell but im unsure.

If anyone could quickly let me know about the answer and possibly briefly why that would be v cool... thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D is the correct answer.

You can put tables in a table, lists in a table and forms in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Answers a, b, c, and d are all correct. Answer d implies the other answers, but this does not make it *the* correct answer. Even answer d does not list *all* the elements that are allowed in a table data cell.

The argument why they are all correct depends on HTML version. For a valid argument, you need to cite authoritative documents, such as the [HTML 4.01 definition of `td`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TD) or the [HTML5 CR definition of `td`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element). The definitions are indirect; e.g., HTML5 specifies the content model as [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1), which in turn is defined in terms of a long list of elements, including `table`, `ul`, `ol`, `dl`, and `form`.